# Avoid appearing double commander dialogs on secondary display

Tags: doublecmd

OS is Ubuntu 20.04. Double Commander is GTK.
When I begin copying some files to a folder by DC, when a confirmation dialog appears for files to be overwritten or something, the dialog appears on the second monitor. When I'm at the console, I just wonder and then find that it has appeared on the second display. But when I'm connecting remotely via Anydesk or something, I wonder what happened and what has cause the copy to stop! Then I remember that the dialog may have appeared on the second display. Then switch monitors and find it.

I need to tell Double Commander not to show its dialogs on the second display. Instead show them on the same monitor as the Double Commander itself is shown. I'm not sure what causes it to choose the other display.

You know what should I do?